# What is legible way of showing different status for different time slots

Tags: website-design

Color coding is what I thought but there are 10 different status.
Example: Color coding: Different color indicating different status from 1pm- 2pm, another color indicating another status from 2pm-3pm.Since there are more than 10 entries for each main entity using color coding =  10 different colors could look cluttered.User remembering so many different colors for each one of the status is not desirable.Any suggestions on how can I  address this design part?

Comment: please give an idea of what exactly 'status' mean. i mean to say, what type of content goes into it

Comment: Could you please provide a screen mockup of your problem? This will help us in understanding your issue.

Comment: I agree, aside from the time slots - why is there a need to colourize individual entries? What is the relational factor?

Comment: Welcome to the UX stack exchange. We genuinely want to help you with your question, but unfortunately as written we're having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Is status linked to time? For example, do all 1-2pm slots have the same status? And do all slots in each status have the same time? If so, then status seems redundant and maybe unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I think the below example would explain my requirement; This data associated with the time slot. 1.Cab booking initiated : Red 2.Cabs Booked in the areas : Orange 3.Cabs free slot in the surrounding areas : yellow 4.Cab booking confirmed : Green 5.Source/pick up Address confirmed : Violet 6.Reached source address: Brown 7.Started from source address : Light blue 8.Reached Destination address : Indigo Blue 9.Booking completed : Gray

Comment: Why not just use something like a progress bar. Your description looks more like a progres than something timeslot related.

Comment: Hi All thanks for the suggestions and the answers I have figured out a way where I have done a grouping of status and then given 4 different colors to each group and the sub status I have indicated using the progress bar along with some text. The design has really simplified for now and looks neat :)I will post the same soon.. Thank guys for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have one serious problem using colour only to define something and that is that there are many variations of colour blindness effecting various individuals ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness)), not to mention a degradation in colour interpretation due to age and the fact some users can't see clearly in the first place. This accounts for quite a few users in total.

Therefore in order to improve the legibility of a set of statuses you must also use text, iconography, contrast or other graphical elements such as borders or gloss.

I would suggest if you want to define statuses that are related to hourly time slots that you use some sort of clock face icon set or for a more granular set use sun and moon icons. You could also output the time / time of day itself clearly as text

For the set of statuses in the comments which mention booked, address confirmed etc. again text would be a good solution, perhaps a two or three letter abbreviation with a key somewhere. This could be backed up with icons.

There is no need to ditch colour altogether, but bear in mind that it cannot be used on it's own to produce something that is legible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can group the statuses by time :

- 7-8am, 8 to 10, 10 to noon are variants of a blue (or even the same blue)
- noon to 2 could be yellow
- anything afternoon and evening is orange

You could group them differently depending on the meaning you want to give to those groups.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I think the below example would explain my requirement; This data associated with the time slot.  1.Cab booking initiated : Red
2.Cabs Booked in the areas : Orange
3.Cabs free slot in the surrounding areas :  yellow
4.Cab booking confirmed : Green
5.Source/pick up Address confirmed : Violet
6.Reached source address: Brown
7.Started from source address : Light blue
8.Reached Destination address : Indigo Blue
9.Booking completed : Gray

Comment: I thought of same when I wanted to optimize the number of colors to be used. But here the timings may not span over for that long. Hence to understand the status by just seeing the colors may become difficult. Any other thoughts would be very helpful. Thanks a lot.